# Why won't @override work?

Tags: android, eclipse, code-generation, overriding, annotations

What is wrong with piece of code?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Eclipse states that @override cant be where it is.
It says that 'Bundle' is wrong.  I am lost.

Comment: I suppose that you are talking about Java. I am not sure but we are not able to help you when there is only this part of your code...

Comment: Going to need more context there, dude.  Does your superclass have a `void onCreate(Bundle)`?  Is `Bundle` imported?  What lines come before and after that line?  What is the *exact* error message?

Comment: i suppose it's android, so retagged it.

Comment: @override should be on the line _above_ the method signature.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy: that is just a convention, it does not matter to the parser.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy: If it is on the same line before the declaration, on the line above or with a couple of empty lines in between really doesn't matter. In this case he is probably trying to override something that doesn't exist with that signature.

Comment: @Fredrik Another possibility is a missing end-brace in the lines above.  Hard to tell without context or an error message.

Comment: Is Bundle valid within the current scope or does it maybe need importing?

Comment: @ZoogieZork: of course, or missing the class or anything else making it misplaced. Hard to say without the actual error or a context.

Comment: Like Rob said, fix your imports.

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
 @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

 }
```

`onCreate` is public, not protected.

Comment: Actually... `onCreate()` is `protected`:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29

Comment: I came back with your corrections but it still won't work.  I will redownload the SDK.  And try again.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So maybe the problem is compiler compliance level: 1.5 instead of 1.6 ?

@Baleisen which level is set for your project?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the android framework but:

First make sure your class **extends** a Class such as (Activity) which contains onCreate. Then try to call super.onCreate, to double check that Class you are extending contains onCreate! ***You could be pointing to another class with the same name.*** Your compiler says that there is nothing to override, if you are sure it is wrong, then either your compiler is out dated or the framework.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //yourCode
    }
```

Also if your extending and extended class, make sure, this method, I posted is in the class extending the class. It could freak out on this.

Answer (score 0):

What your class extends ? And which android SDK version you're compiling ?

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before and the problem was the Android SDK hadn't loaded into Eclipse fully.

Also, do you have this import in your file?  The parent onCreate method is in Activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
```